# Sinatra: NoMethodError at [...] undefined method `body=' for #<String:[...]>

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I got a NoMethodError when trying to return a response in Sinatra. This is the error:

### NoMethodError at /contact/book-me.php

#### undefined method `body=' for #<String:0x00000001911418>

```
/home/kerrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb in body
        response.body = value
/home/kerrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb in invoke
        body res
/home/kerrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call!
      invoke { dispatch! }
/home/kerrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call
      dup.call!(env)
/home/kerrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb in call
        status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
[...]
```

This is the relevant code:

```
# Snipped, but basically populate the @error hash if the form wasn't filled out right
if @error.length == 0
  #Snipped, but basically handle the success case
else
  @response = ''
  @error.each do |x, y|
    @response << "<li>#{y}</li> \n"
  end
  return [400, @response]
end
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@response` as your return value in Sinatra is what's causing your problem. The same problem is [documented on the Ruby on Rails OldWiki](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords), so it's not just Sinatra specific. You should change your code to look something like this and it'll work:

```
else
  @send_errors = ''
  @error.each do |x, y|
    @send_errors << "<li>#{y}</li> \n"
  end
  return [400, @send_errors]
end
```